# add red cross delete functionality onhover in react

Tags: reactjs, onhover

so i have data from api and mapped over them to present these images:

[image: images]

so i'm trying to do this project and now i'm basically stuck i'm not very good in react and css but i'm learning, and i want to do now is to add remove functionality. i have created a function that removes the picture from the data when i click on the image but what i want is when i hover over the image a red cross will appear and when i press the red cross i can trigger the function and delete the image

code:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect,useReducer} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';

const Data = () => {

    const [photo,setPhoto] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos").then(
            result => {
                setPhoto(result.data)
            }
        )
    },[])

    const [Url,setUrl] = useState()
    const[photoId,setPhotoId] = useState()

    const showPicture = (url,id) => {
        setUrl(url)
        setPhotoId(id)
    }


    const handleDelete = id => {
        setUrl(null);
        setPhoto(prevState => prevState.filter(x => x.id !== id));
      };

      const {register,handleSubmit,errors} = useForm();
      const [links,setLinks] = useState({
          link:'',
          thumbnailLink:'',
          title:''
        })

        const onSubmit = (data) => {
            console.log(data)
        };

    return(
        <div>
            <div><img src={Url} onClick={() => handleDelete(photoId)}></img></div>
            <div>Posts</div>
            {/* <p>enter album Id to see the magic</p><input type="text" value={albumId} onChange={e => setAlbumId(e.target.value)}></input>
            <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Fetch Album</button> */}
            <div className="container">
            <div>{photo.slice(0,3).map(p => 
                 <div key={p.id}>
                    <img src={p.thumbnailUrl} thumbnailUrl={p.thumbnailUrl} onClick={() => showPicture(p.url,p.id)}></img>
                        <div>{p.title}</div>
                </div>
            )}</div>
            </div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <input type="url" placeholder="link" name="link" ref={register}/>
                    <input type="url" placeholder="thumbnail url" name="thumbnail" ref={register}/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="title" name="title" ref={register}/>
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Data;
```

Comment: you want to delete picture or complete object from array?

Comment: i want to delete the complete picture from the state yes complete object from the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css `:hover` to display button upon hover. Write a handler for delete and pass the `index` to it and use array `splice` to remove photo.

[Working demo (hover & close functionality)](https://codesandbox.io/s/image-hover-close-icon-fix-m85x8)

**Delete Handler**

```js
const handleImageDelete = id => {
    const updatedPhotos = [...photo];
    updatedPhotos.splice(id, 1);
    setPhoto(updatedPhotos);
  };
```

**JSX**

```js
<div>
      <div className="container">
        <div>
          {photo.slice(0, 3).map((p, i) => (
            <div className="image" key={p.id}>
              <img
                alt=""
                key={p.id}
                src={p.thumbnailUrl}
                thumbnailUrl={p.thumbnailUrl}
                onClick={() => showPicture(p.url, p.id)}
              />
              <div
                className="delete"
                type="button"
                onClick={() => handleImageDelete(i)}
              >
                X
              </div>
              <div>{p.title}</div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Styles**

```js
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.image .delete {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.image:hover .delete {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is add a classname on the delete button and on default set it's css to `display: none` and on it's hover property just set it to `display: unset` and it should work like magic.

I tried to apply it on your code.

I just added a div with x and used an arrow function so I can pass the id of the photo:

`<div className='container-delete' onClick={e => this.handleDelete(p.id)}>X</div>`

and a css style:

```
.container-delete {
 display: none;
 color: red;
}

.container-delete {
 display: unset;
}
```

Here is the complete code (Just add the css in your css file for the hide and show):

```
import React,{useState,useEffect,useReducer} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';

const Data = () => {

    const [photo,setPhoto] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos").then(
            result => {
                setPhoto(result.data)
            }
        )
    },[])

    const [Url,setUrl] = useState()
    const[photoId,setPhotoId] = useState()

    const showPicture = (url,id) => {
        setUrl(url)
        setPhotoId(id)
    }


    const handleDelete = id => {
        setUrl(null);
        setPhoto(prevState => prevState.filter(x => x.id !== id));
      };

      const {register,handleSubmit,errors} = useForm();
      const [links,setLinks] = useState({
          link:'',
          thumbnailLink:'',
          title:''
        })

        const onSubmit = (data) => {
            console.log(data)
        };

    return(
        <div>
            <div><img src={Url} onClick={() => handleDelete(photoId)}></img></div>
            <div>Posts</div>
            {/* <p>enter album Id to see the magic</p><input type="text" value={albumId} onChange={e => setAlbumId(e.target.value)}></input>
            <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Fetch Album</button> */}
            <div className="container">
            <div>{photo.slice(0,3).map(p => 
                 <div key={p.id}>
                    <img src={p.thumbnailUrl} thumbnailUrl={p.thumbnailUrl} onClick={() => showPicture(p.url,p.id)}></img>
                    <div>{p.title}</div>
                    <div className='container-delete' onClick={e => this.handleDelete(p.id)}>X</div>
                </div>
            )}</div>
            </div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <input type="url" placeholder="link" name="link" ref={register}/>
                    <input type="url" placeholder="thumbnail url" name="thumbnail" ref={register}/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="title" name="title" ref={register}/>
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this

```
          {photo.slice(0, 3).map(p => (
            <div key={p.id} onClick={() => deleteIt(p)}>
              <img
                alt="theme"
                src={p.thumbnailUrl}
                thumbnailUrl={p.thumbnailUrl}
                onClick={() => showPicture(p.url, p.id)}
              />
              <div>{p.title}</div>
            </div>
          ))}
```

delete function

```
  const deleteIt = item => {
    let filtered = photo.filter(p => p.id !== item.id);
    setPhoto(filtered);
  };
```

[Live working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-shaw-uudcg?file=/src/App.js:825-938)

Answer (score 0):

You can call method when you are hovering an HTML Element with attribute `onMouseEnter`

Add this attribute in your component :

```
<div key={p.id} onMouseEnter={() => displayRedLine(p.id)}>
  <img src={p.thumbnailUrl} thumbnailUrl={p.thumbnailUrl} onClick={() => showPicture(p.url,p.id)} onMouseen/>
  <p>{p.title}</p>
</div>
```

Create a new state to know if the photo is hovered :

```
const [photoHovered, setPhotoHovered] = useState(0) // It takes the id of hovered photo
```

displayRedLine(String id) method :

```
const displayRedLine = id => {
  setPhotoHovered(id); //It take the id of the photo when it was hovered
```

}

Finally, display a red line with a condition to know if it is hovered thanks to :  
`p.id === photoHovered ? /** make something **/`